# Mvvm application loading data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone application built using the MVVM pattern and I have pages that have to load data. I know this practice is bad but I used an `async void LoadData()` called in the constructor to load data. Are there any better ways to achive this?

Thanks in advance

```
public class SomeViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();   
    }

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        //load data, ex. add items to list
    }

    private RelayCommand _refreshCommand;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RefreshCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _refreshCommand
                ?? (_refreshCommand = new RelayCommand(() => LoadData()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this data need to be loaded asynchronously in the constructor?

Comment: If your LoadData() is async, shouldn't your Command be `new RelayCommand(async () => { await LoadData(); })`?

Comment: @Edin the LoadData is void

Comment: @sidy3d: I do not see a good reason for your method to by `async void`. Maybe you should explain your use case in more detail. What does `LoadData` exactly do and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: LoadData loads days when the view model is first constructed or when the user clicks on the refresh button. In this case I have to get items from a webserver and as them to a list that the view binds to.

Comment: Can't you just call LoadData somewhere else? Where you create the object, for example. You can also make the method async Task, but I guess that wouldn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who's responsible for create view model is Ioc in Locator, so putting your LoadData method on constructor you will not have control.

My advice: Does not load data in Vm constructor. Do like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel: BaseViewModel
{

    public IMessenger Messenger { get { return base.MessengerInstance; } }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Initialize(); 
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterMessengers();
    }

    public void RegisterMessengers()
    {
         Messenger.Register<string>(
            this, "TokenRefresh", u => LoadData(u));
    }

    public async void LoadData(string u)
    {
        //load data, ex. add items to list
    }

    private RelayCommand _refreshCommand;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RefreshCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _refreshCommand
                ?? (_refreshCommand = new RelayCommand(() => LoadData()));
        }
    }
}
```

And you call from another view model like that:

```
_navigationService.Navigate(typeof(YourView));
Messenger.Send("", "TokenRefresh");
```

Comment: An important note: `async void` should **never** be used, except for event handlers.

Comment: @DanielMann Exactly! It's not a good practice. sidy3d You can change for Task or Task<T>.